# Joomla update data in database from form

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I'm using joomla 3.4.6, and Form Maker component, I'm trying to modify the submission page.

I have a table that contains some data and a column with checkboxes. I also have a button "Save"
When I click the button "Save", I want to save the value from the checkboxes in the database (0 for unchecked, 1 for checked)

I hope i'm providing code snippets that makes sense.

**Save button**

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="hide_label_list" value="<?php  echo $lists['hide_label_list']; ?>" /> 
    <input type="button" style="vertical-align:middle; cursor:pointer" value="<?php echo JText::_( 'save' ); ?>" />
</div>
```

**Check boxes from database**

```
    <table class="submissions" width="100%">

        ...

        <tr class="<?php echo "row$k"; ?>">

        <td align="center"><?php echo $www+1+$pageNav->limitstart;?></td>

        <?php
        if(1==1) 
        {
            if($resolved == 0) 
                echo '<td align="center">
                        <input type="checkbox">Closed</input>
                      </td>';
            else
                echo '<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" checked>Closed</input></td>';
        }

        ...

    </table>
```

I checked https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase and other google results, but because I'm new with php/joomla and working on an existent extension [Form Maker] it makes it hard to understand.

Here's the [full php file](http://pastebin.com/TA9MRtyJ) in case it would make more sense

How can I update if checked and click save button?